# How to reset Altium View Configuration Colors?

Tags: altium

How can I go back to the default System Colors in Altium's View Configuration tab?

I've changed the colors but in 3D mode I want to see the original green pcb.

Comment: Change the colors back.

Answer (score 1):

Open the "View Configuration" panel and select the "View Options" tab. In the "Configuration" dropdown select "Altium 3D Dk Green". This will display the default green board in 3D mode.

[image]